Power BI - Calculate revenue based on maturity of the credit installments
I want to perform next revenue forecasting calculation in Power BI. The table below displays a list of credit purchases with an approved number of instalments. The total purchase amount is shown in the ‘Amount’ column. I intend to divide the total amount by the number of approved instalments, allowing me to calculate the monthly payments for the corresponding future months. These payments will commence from the month when the invoice was issued. This process will enable me to forecast expected income by selecting a specific month and year in the future, using a date filter.
This is a table example with the original data:

The next table is a the result I want to get - overview of the expected income based on the maturity of the installment:

I want to make it adaptable to varying numbers of rows in the table if additional lines are added to the table (to dynamically accommodate a table with n rows).

Please paste your table as copiable text.
